Usage/meaning of 了(le) in sentence with the word "to-be"?
I know that when you are saying that something is a noun, you use 是 (shì), but when do you use 了(le)? Is it used when you are saying that an action is being completed or that someone or something is doing something?

The question is too broad. I suggest performing a search, with 了 as the subject, on this forum, or google it on the web to familiarize yourself with the word, then ask something you don't understand.

Basically, 了 is used in one of two ways:

Placed after a verb or adjective (to indicate completion), usually identified as  了1.

Placed at the end of a sentence, or a phrase, usually identified as 了2.


I suppose your question is about 了2, let's compare a few sentences that with and without 了 at the ends - to indicate a change of state, or a condition, with respect to sometimes in the past:

他是(一個)大學生 - He is a college student.

他是(一個)大學生了 - He is a college student now/already. (He wasn't the last time you saw him.)

這房子是我的 - This house is mine.

這房子是我的了 - This house is mine now. (It wasn't before.)

明天是星期六 - Tomorrow is Saturady.

明天是星期六了 - Tomorrow is Saturaday already. (Express the feeling about time changes with a sigh or an expectation.)


You certainly shall search the web to find more instructions on the uses of 了1 and 了2. Have fun :)

Quote:- "When should I use the character 了 to say what something is? I know that in the case of saying that something or someone is a noun, you use 是 (shì), but when is 了 (le) used?"
My answer is based on the assumption that I understand correctly your question or rather the underlying query.
Let's breakdown your question:-

"I know that in the case of saying that something or someone is a noun, you use 是 (shì)"

Correct. For example, "He is a good person", "他是一个好人"

"...but when is 了 (le) used?"

了 is used when the subject, (He), "became" a good person, i.e. used as a past tense marker.
So, we have, "He is a good person", "他是一个好人", turning into "He became a good person", "他成为了一个好人"

"When should I use the character 了 to say what something is?"

Now, is this why you ask about the usage of 了 to mean "to be"?, because "to be" is when "something is", or, something maintaining a contemporaneous form or quality.
I don't think it works that way, as other commentators have also opined.
If I have misunderstood your question, then of course my answer is wrong.

I have never used 了 (le) to mean "to be" in my daily life, and I can't even think of an example where it would work in that context. I haven't seen this usage in any dictionaries either. Where did you come across the idea of 了 meaning "to be"?
